# How can I set a checkbox to default as Intermediate?

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, state

Given the following declaration of a `CheckBox` in XAML created in Visual Studio Community 2015 in C#, how can I define the state of the `CheckBox` to be Intermediate on creation?

```
<CheckBox Margin="95,121,0,807" IsThreeState="True" IsChecked="True">Binary</CheckBox>
```

I have already sifted through the MSDN API for a few hours scanning these pages:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate(v=vs.110).aspx

I cannot seem to find a way to do this. Is it possible to initialize a `CheckBox` to the intermediate state?

Comment: you are looking at the wrong document I guess?  XAML is not WinForm.

Comment: have you tried setting the IsChecked property to null instead? ThreeState basically has True, False or Null... I am not sure how you would set that on the WPF side of things though...

Comment: I am extremely new at C#, as in I just started teaching myself Sunday, so I guess I was a bit confused. Thanks for the clarifications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the checkbox into an indeterminate state from XAML you need to do the following:

```
<CheckBox Name="checkBox1" IsThreeState="True" 
      IsChecked="{x:Null}"/>
```

The `IsChecked` property can be set to `true`, `false` or `null` and while you can simply use the strings "True" and "False" for the first two you have to specify null in this way.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand that. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the IsChecked to null like so:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Null}" IsThreeState="True">Indeterminate?</CheckBox>
</Grid>
```